# Where are rhev templates stored?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, rhev

I would like to modify a Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization (RHEV) template. I know I could just use an existing machine and create a new template from this machine - but it would require updating other references too. So I thought I could just "mount" the template file, do a few edits on the filesystem and be done.

But I can not find the templates - can anyone enlighten me, where these templates are stored? Or in which format, so I know what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template disk image is stored on the storage domain along with the VM  disk images and it can be located via the api or the database. However,  if you change anything on the template you will break every VM created as a linked clone which is why there is no built in option to modify templates.